# Django: Number of ForeignKey Database Queries

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I would just like to clarify something so that I can optimize my Django ORM queries to Postgres through the psycopg2 adapter.

Let's for instance say I have three models:

```
from django.db import models   

class City(models.Model):
     #
     pass

class Person(models.Model):
     hometown = models.ForeignKey(City)

class Book(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Now let's do the following query:

```
book = Book.objects.get(pk = 4)
```

Now if I wanted to know the raw ID of the author, all I would need to do is this

```
>>> raw_id = book.author_id
>>> print raw_id
3
```

My question is, does book.author_id make another hit to the database or does it just grab it from memory since it was already grabbed before hand from the get query? From my understanding, there should only be one trip for this query correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, `book.author_id` does not make another hit on the database, the foreign key ID is stored in book.  You can see check this yourself if you do go to the shell with `DEBUG=True` setting:

```
>>> from django.db import connection

>>> connection.queries
[]

>>> book = Book.objects.get(pk=4)

>>> connection.queries
[{u'sql': u'SELECT "yourapp_book"."id", "yourapp_book"."author_id" FROM "yourapp_book" WHERE "yourapp_book"."id" = 4 ',
u'time': u'0.003'}]

>>> book.author_id
7

>>> connection.queries
[{u'sql': u'SELECT "yourapp_book"."id", "yourapp_book"."author_id" FROM "yourapp_book" WHERE "yourapp_book"."id" = 4 ',
u'time': u'0.003'}]

>>> book.author
<Author: Mark Twain>

>>> connection.queries
[{u'sql': u'SELECT "yourapp_book"."id", "yourapp_book"."author_id" FROM "yourapp_book" WHERE "yourapp_book"."id" = 4 ',
 u'time': u'0.003'},
 {u'sql': u'SELECT "yourapp_author"."id", "yourapp_author"."name" FROM "yourapp_author" WHERE "yourapp_author"."id" = 7 ',
 u'time': u'0.001'}]
```

`connection.queries` lists all the SQL queries being sent through the ORM in the django shell while `DEBUG` is on.  Note only one query was made even after doing `book.author_id`, but a second query was made when we did `book.author` as django had to go back to the database to fetch the author's name to display.

You can avoid that second database query by selecting the book via `book = Book.objects.select_related('author').get(pk=4)`.

```
>>> connection.queries
[]

>>> book = Book.objects.select_related('author').get(pk=4)

>>> connection.queries
[{u'sql': u'SELECT "yourapp_book"."id", "yourapp_book"."author_id", 
  "yourapp_author"."id", "yourapp_author"."name"
  FROM "yourapp_book" LEFT OUTER JOIN "yourapp_author" ON 
  ( "yourapp_book"."author_id" = "yourapp_author"."id" ) WHERE "yourapp_book"."id" = 4 ',
  u'time': u'0.003'}]

>>> book.author
<Author: Mark Twain>

>>> connection.queries
[{u'sql': u'SELECT "yourapp_book"."id", "yourapp_book"."author_id", 
  "yourapp_author"."id", "yourapp_author"."name"
  FROM "yourapp_book" LEFT OUTER JOIN "yourapp_author" ON 
  ( "yourapp_book"."author_id" = "yourapp_author"."id" ) WHERE "yourapp_book"."id" = 4 ',
  u'time': u'0.003'}]
```

I should also note that for debugging the number of queries actually made in a running django application during testing that the tool [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) is invaluable.

Comment: This was very helpful, for all other readers who come across this, this will definitely clear it up!